# ! Missing \endcsname inserted once Miktex upgraded

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, fonts, errors, miktex

I just upgrade Miktex and since then I receive this message and don't know what to do. I tried different possibilities without any success. A minimal example is not possible since to run the .tex file you need .sty file. Please help me and tell me how I can fix that problem. I can upload both .tex file and sty to a hosting site if needed.

(C:/Users/gateway/Documents/MesRecettes\recettes/boulanger/PainCitrouille.tex)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/lm\t1lmr.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/marvosym\umvs.fd")
! Missing \endcsname inserted.

\csname\endcsname
l.111 ...tes/boulanger/PainCitrouille}{vide}{vide}

?
Thanks in advance

Comment: well without code it is not possible to help.

Comment: What's in line 111 of the `PainCitrouille.tex` file? The error message refers to that line

Comment: that is password protected ...

Comment: Download link
https://gofile.io/d/gEVs1B
Edit link
https://gofile.io/d/gEVs1B/edit

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\lettrine` and in its first argument your code inserts a `\stepcounter` command.
That is dangerous as `\lettrine` uses this argument to calculate sizes. Move the `\stepcounter` command before the `\lettrine`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{init}
%this fails:
%\lettrine{\stepcounter{init}\theinit}{text} text 

%this works:
\stepcounter{init}%
\lettrine{\theinit}{text} text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now, that I put setcounter before lettrine it worked fine, But I have a utf8 problem (! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence). The same LaTex file used to work properly in the past with this in the preamble. 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

I don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: if you have new problem, ask a new question. But better learn to make a minimal example. And check all the encodings of your files.